# How to combine 3 file in one editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want show three file in one Eclipse editor. For example I have 3 files. Those are

1. routing
2. jsonMapping
3. model

Those file linked to another file. So How to show this files in one Eclipse editor.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in an editor plugin that you are writing? Or are you asking about using an existing editor?

Comment: create new editer

Comment: The editor `matchingStrategy` is used for this - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592365/2670892)

Comment: No he is open two editer for one file. But i want open 2 file in one editer